# converting timezone back to local

Tags: java, groovy

I'm stuck converting the Date object back to a local timezone. I've googled a lot and couldn't arrive at a solution.

My scenario is: I send a request (with full date string in local timezone 04/01/2014T00:00:00+0530) to a web server which is located in some other timezone than that of mine. The server appropriately converts it to UTC and does some manipulation and sends a CSV file back. I've a date column in CSV which is always in GMT.

```
String input = "04/01/2014T00:00:00+0530";
DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateFormat csvFileDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm z");

Date inputDate = inputDateFormat.parse(input); // Mon Mar 31 18:30:00 GMT 2014
// inputDateFormat.getTimeZone(); // is always GMT

// After some processing I create CSV file
// within a loop
Date csvDate = // got Date from some operation, for simplicity I removed the code.
csvFileDateFormat.format(csvDate); // **HERE IS THE ISSUE**
// end of loop
```

I wanted to set the timezone of csvFileDateFormat correctly. Below code works, but I don't want to hard code "GMT+05:30". Instead need to extract the timezone only from input string.

```
csvFileDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30")); // I dont want to hard code
```

Any help is highly appreciated. 
PS: I don't have option to use any other libraries, like joda, etc...

Regards
ArunDhaJ

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function will help you :

```
private static TimeZone getTimeZoneFromString(String inputDateStr)
{
    // TimeZone inputTimeZone = null;
    // null or default
    TimeZone inputTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    try
    {
        DateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Date inputDate = inputDateFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
        Date inputDate2 = inputDateFormat.parse(inputDateStr.substring(0, 19) + "+0000");
        int offset = (int) (inputDate2.getTime() - inputDate.getTime());
        for (String tzId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs())
        {
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId);
            if (tz.getOffset(inputDate.getTime()) == offset)
            { // take the first matching one, display name doesn't matter
                inputTimeZone = tz;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputTimeZone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remi878. To an extent I've implemented like this only, by parsing the input string (in Groovy)...

    String timeZone = input[-5..-1];
    inputDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + timeZone));


but was wondering if there are any direct methods to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Locale.getDefault()` to return the default timezone for the system it is being run on. If you don't want to return that, then it should be safe to hard code it.